# Who is Shukla Avatar of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, rishi, tantra

The [Satvata Tantra Part 2 Verse 8](https://archive.org/stream/SriSatvataTantraEnglishTranslation_201804/Sri-Satvata-Tantra-English-Translation#page/n4/mode/1up) mentions:

> Seeing Kardama Muni's austerities aimed at attaining mystic powers, the Lord appeared as Sukla in a pure and transcendental form. After giving him the benediction that he would appear as his son, with a tear of bliss the Lord created a holy lake.

I know that the son of Kardama Muni was Kapila who is an incarnation of Lord Vishnu but I want to know who the Shukla avatar was?